Show $0<x<\sqrt[3]{2} \implies \frac{2}{3}(x+\frac{1}{x^2})>\sqrt[3]{2}$
I am trying to show the following result:
$$0<x<\sqrt[3]{2} \implies \frac{2}{3}(x+\frac{1}{x^2})>\sqrt[3]{2}$$ The following is my unsuccessful attempt:
$0<x<\sqrt[3]{2}$
$\implies x^2<(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ and $x>0$
$\implies x^2<\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and $x>0$
$\implies \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}<\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $x>0$
$\implies \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}<\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $x+\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{x^2}$
$\implies x+\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}$
$\implies \frac{2}{3}(x+\frac{1}{x^2})>\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3}$
Any feedback or help is greatly appreciated.

AM-GM inequality
$$x+ x+ \frac{2}{x^{2}}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x\cdot x\cdot\frac{2}{x^{2}}}= 3\sqrt[3]{2}$$
